# how to Make lower case letters for unicode characters

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

I have problem in converting to lower case letters for unicode characters in VC++ MFC .I have unicode characters in a CString Variable.so,with English MakeLower() works fine and I get lower case .But it cannot convert unicode characters to lower case.I did try the STL algorithm transform :

std::string data = "ИИИЛЛЛЛ"; //bulgerian chars

std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);

but it fails to load the unicode chars ,I get "????" symbols in place of unicode chars .

Can you  please let me know if there is a solution for unicode chars .I dont like to use boost libraries.Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::tolower` is character, not byte based and thus cannot perform the operation on non ANSII strings. You should really consider using `boost::locale` in this case.

Comment: @nijansen: He's using the C call `::tolower`, not the C++ `std::tolower<char>`.

Comment: @MSalters you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

If your project uses the Unicode Character Set (project properties), `CString::MakeLower()` should work -- <strike>note that this will not convert the contents of the string</strike>, it returns a new string, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyxcxazf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
CString s1(_T("ABC")), s2;
s2 = s1.MakeLower();
ASSERT(s2 == _T("abc"));
```

**EDIT**: CString::MakeLower() does change the contentrs of the string, it also returns a reference to the converted string

Comment: Thanks for your response,yes my project properties is set to "Use Unicode Character Set" .So ,I dont think MakeLower() will work with Unicode characters.

Comment: it does work for me! (when the project is set to use Unicode Character Set), CString should point to CStringW which supports Unicode) -- see this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms174288.aspx), it says `A CString object supports either the char type or the wchar_t type. Which one it supports depends on which one of the symbols, MBCS or UNICODE, is defined at compile time`

Comment: OK,Thanks .Found the solution .Calling setlocale before CString::MakeLower() works for uniocde lower case conversion.yes,may be if i set properties to MBCS ,it may work.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
std::wstring data = L"ИИИЛЛЛЛ"; // Wide chars

std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), std::tolower<wchar_t>);
```

Comment: Hi MSalters Thanks Now i was able to load the unicode characters ,But even the algorithm fails to convert to lower case for unicode character set

Comment: Thank you all guys !
I found the solution ,We need to set the Locale first before calling the algorith;Works fine now :)
::setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
std::wstring data = L"ИЗПИТВАНЕ"; // Wide chars
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::towlower);

thank you so much MSalters :)

Comment: well to add to this ,I also found that just calling setlocale() even fixes CString::MakeLower() to work with Unicode characters,no need to go for the STL algorithm.Now MakeLower() also works for Unicode characters.

Comment: @Basawaraj this comment should be the accepted answer. Maybe you can answer you own question thus making the solution more visible.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the word *lower* in [IDN2 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/libidn2/reference/libidn2-idn2.h.html), but noticed that domain names are converted to lowercase.  Consider this C snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <idn2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        char *out = NULL, *out2 = NULL;
        int rtc = idn2_to_ascii_8z(argv[i], &out, 0);
        int rtc2 = rtc == 0? idn2_to_unicode_8z8z(out, &out2, 0): -1;
        printf("%2d/%2d  %s -> %s -> %s\n", rtc, rtc2,
            argv[i], out? out: "NULL", out2? out2: "-");
        free(out);
        free(out2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It takes some fancy characters, like [hwair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hwair) but not a simple *°*:

```
ale@alenovo:~/tmp$ gcc -W -Wall -g -O0 lower.c -lidn2
ale@alenovo:~/tmp$ ./a.out ASCII àÃĈOÖÖ°o àÃĈOÖÖo ИИИЛЛЛЛ ǶǶǶǶƕƕƕ
 0/ 0  ASCII -> ascii -> ascii
-304/-1  àÃĈOÖÖ°o -> NULL -> -
 0/ 0  àÃĈOÖÖo -> xn--oo-iiam0ha4k -> àãĉoööo
 0/ 0  ИИИЛЛЛЛ -> xn--h1aaamaaa -> ииилллл
 0/ 0  ǶǶǶǶƕƕƕ -> xn--6haaaaaaa57883c -> ƕƕƕƕƕƕƕ
```