# C++ Code optimization

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have created my custom function to turn a wstring into lower case. However, it is pretty slow in DebugMode. Yes, I know ReleaseMode is what counts, but anyway it is pretty unnerving.

```
wstring wstringToLower(wstring u)
{
    wstring s;

    for (int i=0;i<u.size();i++)
    {
        wstring sChar;
        sChar=u.substr(i,1);

        int iChar=static_cast<int>(sChar[0]);

        int iNewChar=charCodeToLower(iChar);

        wstring sNewChar=wstring(1,iNewChar);

        s.append(sNewChar);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Does anybody see anything obvious that I could improve to speed up the code, even in DebugMode?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case  - I'm afraid your function is about 50 times too complicated for what it does.

Comment: How about just using `tolower` for each character?

Comment: This belongs on **http://codereview.stackexchange.com/**

Comment: @0x499602D2 I need to handle Unicode characters. Standard functions only handle ASCII.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to make temporary strings.

So, for start, instead of:

```
    wstring sNewChar=wstring(1,iNewChar);
    s.append(sNewChar);
```

This should do the trick:

```
    s.push_back(iNewChar);
```

Then, instead of:

```
    wstring sChar;
    sChar=u.substr(i,1);

    int iChar=static_cast<int>(sChar[0]);
```

This should work:

```
    int iChar=static_cast<int>(u[i]);
```

And, of course, as noted by Marcel, you can do everything on the passed copy, avoiding the extra string allocation.

Also, as noted in the comments: [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case) . Also, read all answers (and comments) here: [how to Make lower case letters for unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716080/how-to-make-lower-case-letters-for-unicode-characters) :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

        ::setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
        std::wstring data = L"НЕМАЊА БОРИЋ"; // Wide chars
        std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::towlower);

        // prints немања борић
        std::wcout << data << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower

Comment: There is actually no need for `s` at all.  He could do all the operations on `u` and return it and avoid the extra copy.

Comment: @ZacHowland you're totally right, I don't know how I missed it - just saw it in Marcel's answer.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Thank you. ::setlocale(LC_ALL,""); You are great!

Answer (score 3):

First of all I would avoid to allocate memory for variables each run, since allocating is a heavy operation.

Then do not call u.size() in the for-loop declaration. It will be called every loop otherwise. Every function call less that you call in a loop is a good win for performance.

Next everything Nemanja Boric said in the other answer.

And since the variable u is passed as copy, you can use it as return value and operate directly on it.

```
wstring wstringToLower(wstring u)
{
    int size = u.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        u[i] = charCodeToLower(static_cast<int>(u[i]));
    }

    return u;
}
```

Conclusion: Basically avoid to allocate memory or calling functions in loops. Do just as much as you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no need for the `wstringToLower` function at all.  You can use `<algorithm>` to do most of the work:

```
std::wstring str = "Some String";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::towlower);
```

If you are trying to localize it, you may want to modify it slightly:

```
std::wstring str = "Some String";
std::locale loc; // set your locale
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](wchar_t c)
{
    return use_facet<ctype<wchar_t>>(loc).tolower(c);
});
```